# Chrome onbeforeunload event when tab (or browser) closes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to run a function when the user leaves (closes) the browser or the page and I've got it working in all the browsers except Chrome.

Chrome runs the function successfully if I navigate away from the page but does not run it if I close the tab or close the browser completely.

The function I'm running at the end creates an image and sends some data to my server (similar to any analytic reporting) example: img.src="url?data=yyy". This image is created dynamically with js.

Can someone shed some light what the problem might be?
I have narrowed it down to a couple of reasons:

1) I'm not using the correct event when the tab closes (ie not beforeunload)

2) Chrome actually runs the function but the image doesn't get sent because the browsers/page closes.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the sample code:

```
if(window.addEventListener){
   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", page_unload, false);         
}
function page_unload(){
    var img     = new Image();
    var img_src = "http://www.myurl.com?data=yyy"
    img.src = img_src;
}
```

Comment: each chrome tab is running in it's own process right? So, if you have something running on tab close, even if it runs, the process that contains the running code will stop. Otherwise you could possibly see a bunch of hanging chrome tabs left open, which i've never seen before.

Comment: right, each tab is it's own process..and it would make sense that any code associated with that process ends as well. Firefox handles this situation gracefully and does what I need it to do so I was hoping that I missed something with regards to chrome

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't possible. The `onbeforeunload` event can only really be used to throw up a dialog box to encourage the user to stay on your page (by returning the text to prompt the user with) -- when the event fires, you don't have any time left to make an HTTP request.

Comment: hmmm fair enough....would you know why firefox works in this instance while the others don't? it just bugs me that one would work and the other won't...

Comment: i would theorize that because the process doesn't die, firefox handles tab closures more elegantly. Elegantly being synonymous with complicated in this context.

Comment: @user1394625 It sounds like you're in the hands of the closing speed of chrome. Maybe you can narrow down the size of what you're sending. How big is the image you're sending? Have you tested it out on a pixel image to see if that goes through?

Answer (score 0):

I had a related issue with Chrome and solved it using jQuery:

```
$(window).unload( function() {
   //Call your function
   page_unload();
});
```

For some reason jQuery unload event works better in Chrome in some cases where JavaScript beforeunload does not work properly.